# differential inequality involving the square of the function

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, fluid-dynamics

It is written in a book, (Bertozzi- Majda, vorticity and incompressible flow page 106) that given a differential inequality of the following type:

$ \frac{d}{dt}\|u^{\epsilon}(t)\| \leq c\|u^{\epsilon}(t)\|^2$ we can conclude that $\sup_{t\in [0;T]}\|u^{\epsilon}(t)\| \leq \frac{\|u^{\epsilon}(0)\|}{1-cT\|u^{\epsilon}(0)\|}$ for every $ T < \frac{1}{c\|u^{\epsilon}(0)\|}$.

Can someone explain to me why this is true ?

Thankfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v$ be a solution of the Cauchy problem
$$
\frac{d v}{d t} = c v^2, \quad v(0) = \|u_\epsilon(0)\|.
$$

The following statement is more-less evident

**Proposition 1.** $u(t) \leq v(t)$ for all $t$, where $u(t)$ and $v(t)$ are defined.

($\|u_\epsilon\|$ and $v$ start from equal initial condition $\|u_\epsilon(0)\|$, and the growth rate (derivative) of $\|u_\epsilon\|$ is always less or equal the growth rate of $v$). However, for more rigorous proof, you can proceed with [Gronwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall%27s_inequality). Subtracting equation for $v$ from inequality for $\|u_\epsilon\|$, and denoting $w := \|u_\epsilon\| - v$ we get
$$
\frac{d w}{d t} = c (\|u_\epsilon\|^2 - v^2) = c (\|u_\epsilon\| + v) (\|u_\epsilon\| - v) = c \beta(t) w(t), \quad w(0) = 0,
$$
where $\beta(t) = (\|u_\epsilon\| + v)$. Applying now the Gronwall inequality, we conclude that $w \leq 0$, and hence $u \leq v$.

At the same time, problem for $v$ has an exact solution by separation of variables:
$$
v(t) = \frac{\|u_\epsilon(0)\|}{1 - c t \|u_\epsilon(0)\|}.
$$
It is easy to see that $v(t)$ is monotonically increase, and hence
$$
\sup_{t \in [0, T]} v(t) \leq \frac{\|u_\epsilon(0)\|}{1 - c T \|u_\epsilon(0)\|}.
$$

Using now Proposition 1, we conclude that
$$
\sup_{t \in [0, T]} u(t) \leq \sup_{t \in [0, T]} v(t) \leq \frac{\|u_\epsilon(0)\|}{1 - c T \|u_\epsilon(0)\|},
$$
which is the desired result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is very clear now.
But I think the theorem you used is true for any functional which is locally lipschitz and not just $x \rightarrow x^2$.
Do you know where I could find a proof of this ?

Comment: @incas I think it should be true. Such type of results are called Comparison theorems. Look, for example, here http://books.google.ru/books?id=2szu5oErrKsC&pg=PA203&lpg=PA203&dq=comparison+of+solutions+ode&source=bl&ots=uerWW42GKl&sig=Kw3oLVbJW_9OZwzv_buNHgKZkpQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=Gc9xVI_8G-L4yQOFu4DgBw&ved=0CGAQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=comparison%20of%20solutions%20ode&f=false Lemma 8.4. However, the assumption on the right-hand side there is stronger than you want.

Comment: I am interested by seeing some proper statement and proof of this result, the link you sent me doesn't work can you provide me with some other reference.

Thankfully

Comment: @incas I have found the exact reference. It is in Walter W., "Ordinary differential equations", p.96. "IX. Comparison Theorem.".  It is there.